# Integral Calculus: Plane Areas in Rectangular Coordinates

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

Find the area bounded by the given curves:

$y^2+2x-2y-3=0$ and the $y$-axis

(using horizontal & vertical strip)

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Did you make a graph of the parabola? That could be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Finding the points:

$x = 0$ so
$$ y^2+2(0)-2y-3=0 $$

$$ y^2-2y-3=0 $$

$$ (y-3)(y+1)=0 $$

Thus points $P$ are $(0,3),(0,-1)$.

By completing the square
$y^2-2y+1=-2x+3+1$.

$$ (y-1)^2=-2(2x-2) $$

$ y=1, x=2 ,
V = (2,1) $

The parabola opens left.

Comment: What's the area of the portion of plane delimited by that parabola and that straigth line?

Comment: See [this introductory note](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) about using mathematical expressions in posts, ie. using $\LaTeX$.